# How can you make a logo swipe in, and swipe out of the page, whilst easing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been looking into this for a while now, but had no success I'm afraid.

[This](http://www.stockholmdesignlab.se/farewell/) site has a really cool logo swipe almost, especially in the footer.

When you scroll down, the header logo swipes up, and when you hit the bottom of the page, the logo swipes up and eases in/out.

I've inspected element and found only this related CSS:

```
#wrap .logo-alt {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#wrap .logo-alt.gone {
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:200px;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

It also has:

```
data-scrollspeed="600" and a data-scrollpos="0"
```

jQuery will be in there too I imagine, but how does the effect work exactly? What are the above tags in reference to? I have not come across this before.

Comment: On their own, these data attributes do nothing. However, `data` attributes like `data-scrollspeed` are used by JavaScript frameworks/plugins. jQuery for example has a built-in `.data()` method that will grab the value of a data attribute from whatever element you specify. I'd assume there's a plugin for the animations that looks for certain `data` attrbiutes, and animates the elements accordingly.

Comment: Is that as complicated as it sounds?

Comment: There are plenty of jQuery plugins that you can include in your page that allow you to animate elements simply by giving them attributes, like you see above. All you'd have to do are include jQuery, an animation plugin, read the instructions, and you'd be on your way. The specific website you're looking at just seems to be a basic Wordpress site. Wordpress has themes for you to choose from, most of which have stylish animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cool animation deals with the jQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() <= ###){
        } else {
        }
    });
});
```

I created this [codepen](http://codepen.io/johndurso/pen/5b47b5c93487a325d717b3332dba7e9f) to demonstrate this function for you.

Basically the position on your browser will trigger an animation (in this case I'm just adding and removing classes to the objects).

Comment: Cool thanks! Using your second function, could you detect when it hits the bottom of the page, the entire scroll distance, and then show the logo from the bottom?

Comment: Yup! Since there's not a "scrollBottom" function, you have to create your own variable that does this. 

I've updated my codepen to have the second logo appear once you reach the bottom of the page. Let me know if you have any questions.